# Floating point numbers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, python-3.7

How to get correct number after calculation? For instance, I want 2.2 - 1 equal to 1.2 and not 1.2000000000002. Wanna get exactly correct answer without rounding the number itself and without just simply changing the way of printing the number via print('%1.1f' % number).

Comment: What's wrong with rounding?

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want string formatting, You can do round:

```
>>> a=2.2
>>> b=1
>>> round(a-b,1)
1.2
>>>
```

Comment: I told I don't want number rounding. I need exactly correct answer to operate with.

Answer (score 0):

Use format,

```
In [7]: '{:.2f}'.format(2.2 - 1)
Out[7]: '1.20'
```